# linq subquery child collection to string

Tags: c#, linq, subquery, sum

i am trying to figure out how to write a linq query that will return a child collections "name" property as a string.

I have a BO that has a "options" property where the options are the "name" property of each option in an "order" object.

I would like the result to look something like

```
order.id = 12312
order.date = 12/03/10
order.options = "Option 1 Name, Option 2 Name, Option 3 Name"
```

I hope this makes sense. thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Could you post the class definition for the classes involved in your query? I think this would help make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Aggregate:

```
options.Aggregate((current, next) => current + ", " + next);
```

Note that this generates a new string for each operation, so if your options list is long you are better off using an old school approach with StringBuilder

Answer (score 3):

While [**`Aggregate`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) will work it has O(n<sup>2</sup>) performance. If you need better performance you can use [**`string.Join`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx). Unfortunately this method doesn't accept an `IEnumerable<string>` so you have to also use [**`ToArray`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) to get what you want:

```
string.Join(", ", options.Select(o => o.Name).ToArray())
```